# Как в Yii2 сделать ссылку на скачивание файла с Grid

Tags: yii2

Как в Yii2 сделать ссылку на скачивание файла с Grid?
Сами файлы хранятся в папке на сервере, необходимо их вывести в виде ссылок на скачивание.
Если есть, прикрепите пример кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
           'label'=>'url',
           'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=>function ($data) {
                return Html::a('Тут текст', ['ссылка на url файла']);
            },
    ],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
]); ?>
```